# How to publish Android .aar sources to make Android Studio automatically find them?

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I'm publishing libraries to an internal Sonatype Nexus repository.

Android Studio has a feature that automatically finds the correct source for a library that is referenced through gradle. I publish the sources for our aar as a separate jar to the nexus. 
But Android Studio is not picking them up.

How do I have to publish the sources to make them available in Android Studio?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment.

Comment: Libraries like Retrofit are making there source code available through MavenCentral. Is this a specific feature of Maven Central?

Comment: It's a limitation of Gradle not downloading the source artifacts from a repository when building (because it's not needed when building). We need to get a way to make it download it and expose it through the model sent to the IDE.

Comment: But if I go to a class from for example OkHttp Android Studio shows a button search for source. For most open source libs on Maven Central the source is found and displayed perfectly after clicking this Button. But for our own Repo it is not working.

Comment: FYI retoryfit and okhttp are packed as jar not aar

Comment: Is this still not possible?

Comment: @XavierDucrohet I could instruct Gradle to download the sources of my dependencies (like this https://gist.github.com/stefanhoth/37f86c8e41d648cbd2c8 )but classes from AAR files still can't find the sources. Any chance you will close the gap?

Comment: Two years later and still no solution? I guess documenting stuff is not important on Android.

Comment: @XavierDucrohet As the accepted answer, please consider revising your answer to include more detail on matters such as discussions relating to this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have wrote a [gradle plugin](https://github.com/xujiaao/AARLinkSources) for this function. Hope it will help you.

----- edit ------

**How to publish Android .aar sources?**

```
android {

    task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    }

    artifacts {
        archives sourcesJar
    }

    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this plugin is wrote for gradle 2.+. you can modify the plugin yourself if you need it. just a little change.

Comment: So from my understanding your plugin helps downloading sources for dependencies, but the question here is "How to publish Android..". Can you answer that as well? When knowing that your plugin could be used to read them locally (as well) perhaps?

Comment: I don't think the problem is unpublished sources, it's that Android Studio doesn't know where to look for them for AARs. We publish sources for all internal AARs, but AS still can't find them.